# Sitecore Component Properties Rendering Droplist as Text

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have a component that I've added a parameters template to. The parameters template has a `Droplist` field called `VerticalAlign1`. Its source is set to a folder with three items, `bottom`, `center`, and `top`. Now, in Visual Studio, the dropdown is rendered correctly:

[image: dropdown in visual studio]

However, when one opens up the component properties in the page editor, the following is seen:

[image: text in page editor]

It is simply a text box that gives the content editor no information about what the options may be. Is it possible to have this render as a dropdown?

We're on Sitecore 7.2 MVC.

Comment: What is the field type from the template in Sitecore? Is it still a droplist?

Comment: Check if `Raw values` checkbox is checked.

Comment: @MarekMusielak That's it! Please enter your comment as an answer, so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comment converted into an answer*

In most of the scenarios, the problem is with `Raw values` checkbox being checked.

It changes all the custom field editors into text boxes. That's why you don't see a dropdown list.